# How to convert a Grey Scale image to RGB in C#?

Tags: c#

How to convert a Grey scale image to `RGB` format? I have added **Aforge** library too but unable to define thresholds for coloring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not understand clearly what do you mean under `Convert gray scale image to RGB` and suppose that you are trying to revive colors. Unfortunately it's not possible to do it precisely. I mean you can revive colors from grayscale image but this colors would not exactly the colors was befor transforming to gray. 
Standard transformation from color to grayscale assumes that every pixel of image transformed by formula:

```
G(R,G,B) = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
```

where `R`, `G` and `B` are `RGB` values of pixel

As you understand reverse that transformation may have many different results. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale for more info.

You also may take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31120/Image-Transformation-Grayscale-to-Color) project. It implements solution that makes attempt to revitalize colors from grayscale image. But again, take im mind that this colors would not be an original colors

Answer (score 0):

Anton has a good point which is the resulting colored image will not have the colors in the original image.
This is why coloring a grayscale image is called false coloring I believe.
For images with palette, you can just replace the palette.
For images without palettes, you will have to define a formula to work with.
In our application, we used sdk called leadtools that had functions for coloring gray images and we find it to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using Aforge do this:

```
var filter = new GrayscaleToRGB();
var RGBBitmap = filter.Apply(AForge.Imaging.Image.Convert16bppTo8bpp(bitmap));
```

(if you already have a 8bpp bitmap you can leave out the conversion)

GrayscaleToRGB is in AForge.Imaging.Filters